# AIR (FLEX) and Google Earth Plugin API

Tags: apache-flex, air, google-earth-plugin

At this point Google does not have a Google Earth plugin API for the flash player.  I would still like to use GE in my AIR(Flex) application though.  Can I do this by using the HTML container?  If not what is a possible solution?

Answer (score 2):

You can't do Google Earth (unless you can use an iframe or something).  Instead check out the [3D Google Maps examples](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flex/tourdeflex/web/#docIndex=-1;illustIndex=0;sampleId=15410) in [Tour de Flex](http://flex.org/tour) and see if those might work for you.

Answer (score 1):

you'd better have a [look at this](http://coolestflex.blogspot.com/2008/06/google-earth-with-flex-ie-firefox-on.html)

Comment: It is generally a good idea to include a short description of what the linked page is and how it is helpful in solving the problem.  If possible, include the relevant bits, so even if the page goes away in the future, the solution is still available.